# how to update fields stored in a sqlite database within c#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

i am making an application that lets a user register and login and also change their username sand passwords. when the user is signing up their details are stored in a sqlite database.my problem is that i am not able to update heir account details that are stored in the sqlite database

i have already looked up solutions to this onstack overflaw but i can tseem to find a solution

```
        string oldusername = txtBoxoldUsername.Text;
        string oldpassword = txtBoxoldPassword.Text;
        string newusername = txtBoxnewUsername.Text;
        string newpassword = txtBoxnewPassword.Text;

        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Users.sqlite;Version=3;");

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from UserInfo where UserName like @oldusername and Password = @oldpassword;", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldusername", oldusername);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpassword", oldpassword);
        con.Open();


        SQLiteDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if ((sdr.Read() == true))

        {
            //this is where i am trying to put the code that updats the users username and password 
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password",
                            "Incorrect details entered");
        }
```

i have tried everything i can but i still can seen to update my database.so it will be great if someone can code it in where i have left the comment the name for my database is Users and my table is called UserInfo

Comment: Where is the UPDATE code you need help with???  Also you should never, ever store passwords as plaintext in a DB.  Hash them and salt them.

Answer (score 0):

You need a seperate SQL Lite Command to make an update, somthing like:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "[Update SQL script]";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```